# Sending an email from R using the sendmailR package

Tags: macos, email, r

I am trying to send an email from R, using the [sendmailR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/index.html) package.  The code below works fine when I run it on my PC, and I recieve the email.  However, when I run it with my macbook pro, it fails with the following error:

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- sprintf("<sendmailR@%s>", Sys.info()[4])
to <- "<myemail@gmail.com>"
subject <- "TEST"
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
    control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))

Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25 cannot be opened
```

Any ideas as to why this would work on a PC, but not a mac?  I turned the firewall off on both machines.

Comment: have you tried a different port, ie 587?

Comment: @wkmor1 I tried to set port 587 in the sendmailR control parameter, but it still seemed to be communicating over 25.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you able to send email via the command-line?

So, first of all, fire up a Terminal and then

```
$ echo “Test 123” | mail -s “Test” user@domain.com
```

Look into `/var/log/mail.log`, or better use

```
$ tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

in a different window while you send your email. If you see something like

```
... setting up TLS connection to smtp.gmail.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]:587
... Trusted TLS connection established to smtp.gmail.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]:587:\
    TLSv1 with cipher RC4-MD5 (128/128 bits)
```

then you succeeded. Otherwise, it means you have to configure you mailing system. I use `postfix` with Gmail for two years now, and I never had have problem with it. Basically, you need to grab the Equifax certificates, `Equifax_Secure_CA.pem` from here: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/. (They were using Thawtee certificates before but they changed last year.) Then, assuming you used Gmail,

1. Create `relay_password` in `/etc/postfix` and put a single line like this (with your correct login and password):

   ```
   smtp.gmail.com login@gmail.com:password
   ```

   then in a Terminal,

   ```
   $ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/relay_password
   ```

   to update Postfix lookup table.
2. Add the certificates in `/etc/postfix/certs`, or any folder you like, then

   ```
   $ sudo c_rehash /etc/postfix/certs/
   ```

   (i.e., rehash the certificates with Openssl).
3. Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` so that it includes the following lines (adjust the paths if needed):

   ```
   relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
   smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_password
   smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
   smtp_tls_security_level = may
   smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/postfix/certs
   smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/etc/postfix/smtp_scache
   smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
   smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
   tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
   ```
4. Finally, just reload the Postfix process, with e.g.

   ```
   $ sudo postfix reload
   ```

   (a combination of `start`/`stop` works too).

You can choose a different port for the SMTP, e.g. 465.
It’s still possible to use [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) without [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (the above steps are basically the same), but in both case the main problem is that your login informations are available in a plan text file... Also, should you want to use your MobileMe account, just replace the Gmail SMTP server with `smtp.me.com`.