# issue using sendemailR

Tags: r, email, sendmailr

I am trying to use sendemailR package in R but I am getting an error I don't know how to fix.

When trying the default parameters:

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- "your_email"
to <- "your_email"
subject <- "Test send email in R"
body <- "It works!"                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com")
sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)
```

I get the error

```
Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
Gmail SMTP Server:25 cannot be opened
```

So I change the port to 465 and it seems to work

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- "your_email"
to <- "your_email"
subject <- "Test send email in R"
body <- "It works!"                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com", smtpPort="465")
sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)
```

but then I get the following error

```
Error in if (code == lcode) { : argument is of length zero
```

Any idea what's happening?

This is the version of R and Windows

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Thanks!

Comment: smtp.gmail.com requires authentication, which is not supported by sendmailR

Comment: I also think that `to` should contain a valid email address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that need attention in your example:

As [@David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) commented, `to` should contain a valid email address.

The second thing is the smtp server you are using: `smtp.gmail.com`. This server need authentication which is not supported by sendmailR.

You can use an smtp server that does not require authentication (e.g. the restricted gmail smtp server: aspmx.l.google.com, port 25, see [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) for details)

The other option is to use the `mailR` package that allows authentication.

Try something like (of course you have to put valid email addresses and user.name and passwd to work):

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("RECIPIENT@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
to = recipients,
subject="Subject of the email",
body = "Body of the email",
smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
        user.name="YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com", passwd="YOURPASSWORD", ssl=TRUE),
authenticate = TRUE,
send = TRUE)
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Thanks, mailR works perfect for me. I actually wanted to send attachments on the mail and I can do it with this package.