# R sendmail ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25 cannot be opened

Tags: java, r, sendmail

everyone, I wish you would be kind enough to give me a hand.

I am trying to send a mail through R and have met some problems.

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- sprintf("<sendmailR@\\%s>", Sys.info()[4])
to <- "<myemail@gmail.com>"
subject <- "Hello from R"
body <- list("It works!", mime_part(iris))
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))


Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25 cannot be opened
```

My OS is Windows 7 professional.
Java version is: java version "1.7.0_25"

Thank you so much!

[Sending an email from R using the sendmailR package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864400/sending-an-email-from-r-using-the-sendmailr-package)
the link is about the same question but on linux system.

Could someone be so kind to enlighten me on Windows System?

Thank you again!

Comment: Try "smtp.gmail.com"; Maybe try [this guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_6785249_send-using-gmail-smtp-server.html).

Comment: I guess the problem might be somewhere of the java environment.

Answer (score -1):

You could give the mailR package a try: http://rpremraj.github.io/mailR/