# What `control` settings are valid to send automated emails from Outlook using `sendmailR`?

Tags: r, sendmailr

> EDIT: I found a solution. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074411/send-authenticated-mails-via-outlook-through-r-using-mailr-package). I had to resort to using `mailR`. I could never get `sendmailR` to work with the Office 365 services.

I am trying to send a single email using `library(sendmailR)` to later send daily automated emails to about 500 people. Unfortunately, I'm suck in step 1.

It is vital that I send these emails from my institution's Outlook account. I have no idea what `control` settings to use in order to successfully send mails from Outlook. I checked a couple of questions but they are either using the gmail SMPT server or they do not specify the `control = ...` settings they used. For example:

[Use sendmailR with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421130/use-sendmailr-with-windows)

[Sending an email from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864400/sending-an-email-from-r-using-the-sendmailr-package)

This is what I'm working with:

```
from <- "<myaccount@institution.org>"
to <- "<boss@institution.org>"
subject <- "Hello from R"
body <- list("It's working.")

sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
         control = list(smptServer = "oultook.office.365", port = 443))
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in wait_for(code) : 
SMTP Error: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail 
during MAIL FROM [SN4PR0501CA0061.namprd05.prod.outlook.com]
```

I believe I'm not specifying the port correctly. The [sendmaiLR documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf) is not specific enough, but something tells me I should be writing the port as `"port 443"`or something along those lines.

Does anyone know what `control`settings I should be using?